# How to convert Excel date/time to epoch

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I Googled and found a formula that is supposed to convert from Excel date/time to epoch time.  However, it's off (or I'm off) and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm using http://www.epochconverter.com/ as my source of truth.

So the [link I found](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/49217-converting-normal-time-epoch-time-format-using-excel.html) says the formula is:

```
=(A1-25569)*86400
```

I think `25569` is the Excel value for DATEVALUE("1-1-1970") but for some reason my version of Excel says that's `24107` so I made some modifications and typed:

```
=((A2-DATEVALUE("1/1/1970"))*86400 - 8*3600 (for PST)
```

Now the number is a little more correct.  However, it seems like I need to **ADD** 8*3600 instead of **SUBTRACT**.

Can someone explain to me why?

I thought PST is -8 from GMT.

Comment: just did a quick check for me in NZ which is currently -13 from GMT and the following equation seems correct `=((A2-DATEVALUE("1/1/1970"))*86400-13*3600)`, what do you have in A2

Comment: @Calum, thx for your help.  the A column has the date/time in this format:  3/1/15 10:00.  I have another column where I have the epoch time from http://www.epochconverter.com/ and I compare my value with that value.  My value is off by 57600 sec from the epochconverter.com value.  If I change the - to a +, then the values are identical but logically doesn't make sense to me other than I made a mistake since my time zone is -8

Comment: that should work, provided your excel is in the same timezone (ie PST)

Comment: @Calum, how can I tell which timezone my excel is in?  it's running on my laptop, which is running in the PST timezone.  My laptop time is also "set to set timezone automatically using current location"

Comment: then it should be correct. does `=NOW()` give your current local time?

Comment: yes, it printed the correct local time.  hmmm, very, very strange.  Must be gremlins.

Comment: @pnuts, shoot, you're right.  i'm using a mac.  i forgot to mention i'm on a mac.  X-(   that's what's causing this weird offset?   X-(   how do I make not ask me to +8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

Your Excel is using the 1904 date system.

IF your Excel times start off as ‘local’ don’t adjust for time zone. IF they start as GMT (a concept Excel does not have) then, because when a GMT clock ticks on to 16:00 a ‘local’ clock should tick on to 08:00, from Excel to ‘local’ means deducting 8 hours. Note that midnight 31/12/1969 is not the same instant GMT as PST.